# Erro ao deletar arquivo no Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#

Estou trabalhando em um projeto para windows mobile 6.5. Estou utilizando C# com *compact framework 3.5* (CF 3.5) e o SDK para Windows Mobile 6.5.

Minha rotina grava arquivos em um diretório temporário para um processamento posterior. Após alguns dias o arquivo é renomeado e direcionado para um expurgo.

Ao tentar deletar o arquivo ocorre o seguinte erro: **Access to the path '\Application Data\Volatile\Temp\20170822-97703.Nf.env' is denied.**.

Onde:

- **\Application Data\Volatile** é o diretório temporário padrão `Path.GetTempPath()`
- **\Temp** é o meu diretório temporário `diretorioTemp`
- **20170822-97703.Nf.env** é o nome do meu arquivo.

Segue o código utilizado:

```
const string diretorioTemp = "Temp";

public void ExpurarArquivosEnviados()
        {
            DateTime dataBaseExpugo = new DateTime();
            dataBaseExpugo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
            var arquivos = BuscarArquivosExpurgo();

            foreach (string nomeArq in arquivos)
            {
                var dataAlteracao = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(nomeArq);
                if (dataAlteracao < dataBaseExpugo)
                {                    
                    Directory.Delete(nomeArq);
                }
            }
        }

private string[] BuscarArquivosExpurgo()
        {
            string searchPattern;
            string diretorioLocal;

            diretorioLocal = Path.GetTempPath();
            diretorioLocal = Path.Combine(diretorioLocal, diretorioTemp);

            if (Directory.Exists(diretorioLocal))
            {
                searchPattern = "*.Env";
                var arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(diretorioLocal, searchPattern);
                return arquivos;
            }
            else
                return new string[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir excluir e não ocorrer o erro de acesso negado alterei a linha

`Directory.Delete(nomeArq);`

pelo linha

`File.Delete(nomeArq);`